# Laravel login just redirects back to login page

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx

I've had no luck finding an answer to this, please comment with what information you'd like me to share to help diagnose.

I have a laravel app which works perfectly fine in development, i develop on docker and the live servers use a docker swarm. The login page loads up fine, the database is connected fine and the user exists, but when i log in it just keeps redirecting back to the login screen.

The setup on the production server runs via an nginx reverse proxy to an nginx docker container with a php-fpm container linked. I'm wondering if this is somehow something to do with the reverse proxy which i don't use on the local development copy, so i'm pasting the reverse proxy config in case it helps:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /usr/local/etc/ssl/certs/live/example.com/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/etc/ssl/certs/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;
        ssl_verify_client off;
        server_name admin.example.com;
        error_log /usr/share/nginx/logs/error-admin.log;
        access_log /usr/share/nginx/logs/access-admin.log;
        client_max_body_size 1024M;
        location / {
            proxy_read_timeout 1800;
            proxy_connect_timeout 60;
            proxy_send_timeout 60;
            proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_502;
            proxy_next_upstream_tries 10;
            proxy_pass http://admin;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-XSS-Protection 1;
            proxy_set_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
            proxy_set_header Referrer-Policy origin;
            proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
            proxy_set_header Host admin.example.com;
            proxy_request_buffering off;

        }
    }
```

As i say let me know if you need any more details from other places, i'm not sure where to look for the answer to this.

The access log of the reverse proxy does show a 302 redirect after posting to login, not sure if this is any help:

8

> 6.147.208.76 - - [04/Jun/2022:15:20:03 +0000] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302 386 "https://admin.example.com/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh;
> Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Version/15.3 Safari/605.1.15"

Comment: I would check the middleware...

Comment: What is the exact value of `Location` HTTP header returned by this redirect?